# Sequelize always sets defaultValue event though it's not null

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I've stumbled upon some strange behaviour here. I have an id property defined like this:

```
id: {
    type: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUIDV4,
}
```

So the idea here is to set id to random uuid if it's not passed when model gets created. But when I try to create a model like so

```
const newMessage = new RequestMessage();
newMessage.id = messageId;

console.log({messageId, a: newMessage.id});

await newMessage.save();
```

`newMessage.id` property is not changed and log shows that `newMessage.id` and `messageId` hold different values.

The model itself is defined like so
**RequestMessage.ts**:

```
export default class RequestMessage extends DefaultModel<RequestMessage> {

}

RequestMessage.init({
    id: templates.id
    ...
}, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'request_messages',
    underscored: true,
});
```

**DefaultModel.ts**:

```
export default class DefaultModel<T extends Model<any, any>> extends Model<InferAttributes<T>, InferCreationAttributes<T>> {
    declare id: CreationOptional<string>;
}
```

Did anybody also have this issue? How did you fix it?

Thank you!

**P.S.** It works if I pass id to constructor like

```
const newMessage = new RequestMessage({id: messageId});
```

but it's not very convenient to use everywhere

**P.P.S** Also it works if I disable `defaultValue` for this column, but it also feels wrong